# Stop Apache Camel from starting LevelDB until the route using it is started

Tags: apache-camel, aggregate, failover, leveldb

I have an Apache Camel Route that uses LevelDB as the aggregation repository. My problem is that when the Camel Context is started the LevelDBAggregationRepository is automatically started by Camel even if the Camel Route it is used in is off and not started.

Is there a way of preventing this?

Why is this important for me? I want my application to be highly available, so I want to share the same LevelDB between nodes. But the LevelDBAggregationRepository unfortunately does not support using multiple processes at a time, and I have no SQL DB available for the JDBC Aggregation Repository.

So, my current solution attempt is to use a route policy that ensures that only one node at a time has the Camel Route enabled (determined by leader election with Zookeeper). However, when I start a second node with the route turned off, its Camel Context tries to launch the LevelDB anyway and then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: How have you setup the aggregation repository in your Camel application

Comment: @ClausIbsen: The aggregation repository uses default configurations plus sync=true (defaults are: useRecovery=true, maximumRedeliveries=0, returnOldExchange=false, recoveryInterval=5000, deadLetterUri=null, allowSerializedHeaders=false)

Comment: Yeah this is not supported in camel-leveldb as the repo is eager started when camel starts. You can build your own facade repo and then dont start the leveldb repo in the doStart method, but built into some logic to start it on first use.

Comment: I tried building my own facade repo, but Camel seems to not only start the LevelDB repo, but also performs some follow up actions on the repo (ex: getKeys()) where it assumes that the repo is started. Obviously,the facade could include workarounds for this too, but then the facade gets too complicated and fragile.